# How to create a folder then create a csv file inside it

Tags: c#

I have an exe that already creates a csv file. If I save the exe in C:/EXE, then the cvs file automatically gets created in C:/EXE folder.
C# code uses StreamWriter to accomplish this:

```
using (TextWriter log = new StreamWriter(errorLog + errorBatchNumber.ToString("000") + ".csv", true))
{
    if (errorCount == 0)
    {
        log.WriteLine("Error message");
    }
    log.WriteLine(link.StatusMessage);
    log.Close();
}
```

What I need to add:

1. A folder needs to be created first where the csv file will be saved.
2. This folder will be created where the EXE was saved, in this example: C:/EXE
3. After folder and cvs file was created, it needs to be zipped thru code. (But I need to accomplish first 1 and 2)

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance guys! :)

Comment: Btw, you don't need to close the TextWriter at the end of the using block, it does it automatically.

For folder creation, check the DirectoryInfo class

Comment: read `Directory` and `File` classes from `System.IO` namespace

Comment: The approach that I saw for this requires the path to be given. But the EXE can be saved anywhere so I cannot have a constant pathname...

Comment: You could determine the path with `Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`. But you probably won't have the permission to create a directory there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the path where the EXE will be saved then

1. Directory.CreateDirectory(path + folderName) to create folder
2. To zip items use SharpZipLib at
   http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/ or http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/SharpZipLib_MainPage.ashx

Comment: The EXE can be saved anywhere..So i cannot use a constant pathname.

Comment: In that case please pass the path & name by parameter

Answer (score 1):

Would be something like

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\exe");
if(!di.Exists)
    di.Create();
```

Then you can use `di.FullName` to get the directory to save your file into.

Syntax might be a bit off but it should be enough to get you started. You can check out the [MSDN on DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) as well.

Comment: The EXE can be saved anywhere..So i cannot use a constant pathname

Comment: Well it would be something to get you started. You don't say that it's a winforms app or not, but if you are allowing the user to pick the save location you would use `FolderBrowserDialog` to pick your folder to save the data in. You would pass your `.SelectedPath` to `DirectoyInfo(xxx)`.